# Generating sawtooth wave with python math module

Tags: python-3.x

I know I can do this with scipy or numpy, but I want to do it with just built-in modules in this case. So far, I have come up with this code to generate samples of a sawtooth wave of a specific frequency, at a specific sampling rate (and plot it):

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sawtooth_sample(amplitude, freq, samplerate, i):
    value = math.atan(math.tan(2.0 * math.pi * float(freq) * (float(i) / float(samplerate))))
    return amplitude * value

def plot_samples(num_samples, frequency):
    # Generate the samples
    samples = []
    for i in range(num_samples):
        samples.append(sawtooth_sample(1.0, frequency, 44100, i))

    # Plot the samples
    plt.plot(samples)
    plt.show()
```

So, then I do this to test it:

```
# Generate 1000 samples of a 100Hz sawtooth wave, sampled at 44.1KHz
plot_samples(1000, 100)
```

And, I get this:

[image: low-frequency-sawtooth]

Great. Looks very sawtooth-y.

But, when I try with a higher frequency, like this:

```
# Generate 20 samples of a 10KHz sawtooth wave, sampled at 44.1KHz
plot_samples(20, 10000)
```

Then I get this:

[image]

Not very sawtooth-y any more. Looks more like a triangle wave, with a low harmonic that is sawtooth-shaped. What am I doing wrong and/or missing here?

Comment: Looks like your problem is that the frequency is too high compared to the sample rate, so you have aliasing.

Comment: the signal is 10KHz, and the sampling rate is 44.1KHz, so that's at least 4 samples per waveform period right? I thought that would be a high enough sampling rate to prevent this kind of aliasing. Also, if I run this same test with a sine wave, there is no such aliasing problem at the same frequency. So, I was thinking my code for sawtooth waves was just wrong.

Comment: A sawtooth wave has harmonics at every multiple of the fundamental frequency, but only the fundamental and first harmonic are below the Nyquist frequency of 22.05kHz. So all harmonics except the first one are aliased. A simple sine wave has no harmonics so there is no aliasing.

Comment: ok, so basically when I did the sine wave test, there was aliasing but it was just not as noticeable

Comment: No, a sine wave has no harmonics above the fundamental frequency, so if the fundamental frequency is less than the Nyquist frequency then there is no aliasing.

Comment: Ah, OK. thanks for the info. So the approach I'm using to generate those samples is not ideal then. Google search tells me that generating "bandwidth-limited wavetables" is maybe a better way to go if I want to reduce this kind of aliasing, I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/synthesizers/comments/cbkf1r/python_script_to_create_custom_wavetables_based/. I'll try it.