# How to interactively control the amplitude and frequency of a signal with two scale sliders using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, waveform

Just starting out with python, I want to model a triangular signal and be able to control its amplitude and frequency in an interactive way using scale/sliders widgets, and `Tkinter` as possible.

Inappropriately, my (updated) code below generate two signals (amplitude and frequency) which are controlled by the sliders independently of each other. This isn't surprising because I didn't link these two. However, there are no examples on internet explaining in a didactic way how to do it (`matplotlib`, in particular `.set_ydata` allows this interactivity -[see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html)- but I would really like to understand in detail the binding process and if this is possible with `Tkinter`).

So, the **question** is: How to bind the 2 sliders so that they control a single signal, that is to say when we move one, the other variable remains in its last position?

Thanks for help or any advice

**Code:**

```
# import modules
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

# create window
root = tk.Tk() # object root
root.title('Oscilloscope')
root.geometry("1200x600+200+100")

# exit button
btn_exit = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy, height=2, width=15)
btn_exit.place(x=1100, y=500, anchor=tk.CENTER)

# canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 400, bg = 'white')
canvas.place(x=600, y=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
for x in range(0, 800, 50): canvas.create_line(x, 0, x, 400, fill='darkgray', dash=(2, 2)) # vertical dashed lines every 50 units
for x in range(0, 400, 50): canvas.create_line(0, x, 800, x, fill='darkgray', dash=(2, 2)) # horizontal dashed lines every 50 units
canvas.create_line(400, 0, 400, 800, fill='black', width=2) # vertical line at x = 400
canvas.create_line(0, 200, 800, 200, fill='black', width=2) # horizontal line at y = 200
canvas.create_rectangle(3, 3, 800, 400, width=2, outline='darkgrey')

# parameters triangular signal
amplitude = 200
frequency = 10
nb_pts = 20 # must be necessary 2 fold the frequency for a triangular signal
offset = 200

# function for drawing the triangular signal
def draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts):
    xpts = 1000 / (nb_pts-1)
    line = []
    for i in range(nb_pts):
        x = i * xpts
        y = amplitude * ((2 * (i * frequency / nb_pts) % 2 - 1)) + offset
        line.extend((x, y))
    canvas_line = canvas.create_line(line, fill="red", width=3)
    canvas.after(50, canvas.delete, canvas_line)

# vertical widget scale for amplitude ###############################################################################################
def amplitude_value(new_value): # show value
    label_amplitude.configure(text=f"Amplitude {new_value}")

def select_amplitude():
    sel = "Value = " + str(value.get(amplitude))
value_amp = tk.IntVar()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.place(x=100, y=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
scale_amplitude = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_amp, command=amplitude_value,
                           from_ = 200, to = -200, length=400, showvalue=0, tickinterval=50, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
scale_amplitude.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=10)
label_amplitude = ttk.Label(root, text="Amplitude", font=("Arial"))
label_amplitude.place(x=110, y=480, anchor=tk.CENTER)

def update_amplitude():
    amplitude = scale_amplitude.get()
    draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts) 
    root.after(50, update_amplitude)
    return amplitude

# horizontal widget scale for frequency ###########################################################################################
def frequency_value(new_value): # show value
    label_frequency.configure(text=f"Frequency {new_value}")

def select_frequency():
    sel = "Value = " + str(value.get(frequency))
value_freq = tk.IntVar()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.place(x=600, y=520, anchor=tk.CENTER)
scale_frequency = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_freq, command=frequency_value,
                           from_ = -50, to = 50, length=800, showvalue=0, tickinterval=10, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
scale_frequency.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=10)
label_frequency = ttk.Label(root, text="Frequency", font=("Arial"))
label_frequency.place(x=600, y=560, anchor=tk.CENTER)

def update_frequency():
    frequency = scale_frequency.get()
    draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude , frequency, offset, nb_pts)
    root.after(50, update_frequency)
    return frequency

# reset function
def reset_values():
    value_amp.set(0)
    amplitude_value(0)
    value_freq.set(0)
    frequency_value(0)

# reset button
btn_reset = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset_values, height=2, width=15)
btn_reset.place(x=1100, y=400, anchor=tk.CENTER)

update_amplitude()
update_frequency()

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

Thanks to acw1668's answer, the two sliders now interact and the signal is fully controllable, as updated in the new version of the code below (note that now, the triangular signal is built using `signal` from `scipy`).

Thanks for all

**Updated code**

```
# import modules
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sg

# create window
root = tk.Tk() # object root
root.title('Oscilloscope')
root.geometry("1200x600+200+100")

# exit button
btn_exit = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy, height=2, width=15)
btn_exit.place(x=1100, y=500, anchor=tk.CENTER)

# canva of internal grid
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 400, bg = 'white')
canvas.place(x=600, y=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
for x in range(0, 800, 50): canvas.create_line(x, 0, x, 400, fill='darkgray', dash=(2, 2))
for x in range(0, 400, 50): canvas.create_line(0, x, 800, x, fill='darkgray', dash=(2, 2))
canvas.create_line(400, 0, 400, 800, fill='black', width=2)
canvas.create_line(0, 200, 800, 200, fill='black', width=2)
canvas.create_rectangle(3, 3, 800, 400, width=2, outline='darkgrey')

# parameters triangular signal
nb_pts = 2500
x_range = 800
offset = 200

# updated draw_triangular()
def draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts):
    canvas.delete("line")  # clear current plot
    x_pts = x_range / (nb_pts-1)
    line = []
    for i in range(nb_pts):
        x = (i * x_pts)
        y = amplitude * sg.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * frequency * i/nb_pts, width=0.5) + offset
        line.extend((x, y))
    canvas.create_line(line, fill="red", width=3, tag="line")

# function to be called when any of the scales is changed
def on_scale_changed(*args):
    amplitude = value_amp.get()
    frequency = value_freq.get()
    draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts)

# vertical widget scale for amplitude ###############################################################################################
def select_amplitude():
    sel = "Value = " + str(value.get(amplitude))
value_amp = tk.IntVar()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.place(x=100, y=250, anchor=tk.CENTER)
scale_amplitude = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_amp, command=on_scale_changed,
                           from_ = 200, to = -200, length=400, showvalue=1, tickinterval=50, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
scale_amplitude.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=10)
label_amplitude = ttk.Label(root, text="Amplitude", font=("Arial"))
label_amplitude.place(x=110, y=480, anchor=tk.CENTER)

# horizontal widget scale for frequency #############################################################################################
def select_frequency():
    sel = "Value = " + str(value.get(frequency))
value_freq = tk.IntVar()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.place(x=600, y=480, anchor=tk.CENTER)
scale_frequency = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_freq, command=on_scale_changed,
                           from_ = 0, to = 50, length=800, showvalue=1, tickinterval=5, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
scale_frequency.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, padx=10)
label_frequency = ttk.Label(root, text="Frequency", font=("Arial"))
label_frequency.place(x=600, y=530, anchor=tk.CENTER)

# reset function
def reset_values():
    value_amp.set(0)
    value_freq.set(0)
    canvas.delete("line")
# reset button
btn_reset = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset_values, height=2, width=15)
btn_reset.place(x=1100, y=400, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @toyota, unfortunately no, I really need a triangular signal (possibly a sawtooth signal with width=0.5?)

Comment: FYI: You should be using only one of `from tkinter import *` or `import tkinter as tk` (preferably the latter), not both. See [why star imports are a bad idea](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason to avoid matplotlib or scipy? It's almost always better to use the right tool(s) for the job.

Comment: @JRiggles, thanks, but if I disable `from tkinter import *`, I get the message "NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined. Did you mean: 'tk'?" (for `root = Tk()`, line 9), and if I disable `import tkinter as tk`, I get the inverse message "NameError: name 'tk' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Tk'?" (for `value_amp = tk.DoubleVar()`, line 62)...not very simple for a beginner. And yes, I know that this case could be easily solved using matplotlib, but I want to learn progressively the basics of the python language, first starting with Tkinter.

Comment: You're getting the `NameError` because when you use `import tkinter as tk` you need to prefix tkinter objects with `tk.`, e.g.: `tk.Tk()`, `tk.Canvas`, etc. (FWIW, it's the same thing as what you're already doing with ttk, e.g. `ttk.Frame`). I can see that *some* of your widgets are already instantiated this way, like `tk.Scale` - you just need to do that for all the tkinter objects. Also, I'd argue that you'll have a much easier/less frustrating time learning if you learn to use the proper available tools from the start.

Comment: ok, thank you for the advice and the explanation, and yes, you are right about the easier use of matplotlib, I would think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind the `command` option of the two scales to same function, and get the values of *amplitude* and *frequency* inside that function and call `draw_triangular()` with these values.

```py
...

# updated draw_triangular()
def draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts):
    canvas.delete("line")  # clear current plot
    xpts = 1000 / (nb_pts-1)
    line = []
    for i in range(nb_pts):
        x = i * xpts
        y = amplitude * ((2 * (i * frequency / nb_pts) % 2 - 1)) + offset
        line.extend((x, y))
    canvas.create_line(line, fill="red", width=3, tag="line")

...

# function to be called when any of the scales is changed
def on_scale_changed(*args):
    amplitude = value_amp.get()
    frequency = value_freq.get()
    draw_triangular(canvas, amplitude, frequency, offset, nb_pts)

...

scale_amplitude = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_amp, command=on_scale_changed,
                           from_ = 200, to = -200, length=400, showvalue=0, tickinterval=50, orient = tk.VERTICAL)

...

scale_frequency = tk.Scale(frm, variable=value_freq, command=on_scale_changed,
                           from_ = -50, to = 50, length=800, showvalue=0, tickinterval=10, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)

...

# reset function
def reset_values():
    value_amp.set(0)
    value_freq.set(0)
    canvas.delete("line")

...
```

Note that in this case, you don't need to call the below two *after loops*.

```
update_amplitude()  # don't call it
update_frequency()  # don't call it
```

Comment: Thank you acw1668, your proposal works well. I've updated the code (see Edit) and added a new question about a somewhat strange phenomenon (let me know if this should be the subject of a new post).

Comment: @denis It is better to create another question as the new issue is not related to this question.

Comment: thanks, I've deleted the new question (which is solved by increasing nb_pts from 20 to e.g. 2500, see <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543325/generating-sawtooth-wave-with-python-math-module>). In the (re)updated code, I now use the sg.sawtooth (signal) option from scipy to model the triangular wave in an easier way.